# PostgreSQL - Invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe7 0x75 0x20

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, logging, postgresql

Here is the problem :

Everything worked fine with my postgresql system until I decided to click on the "rotate logs" button in the server status tab (from pgAdmin).
After that, I faced this issue, and cannot solve it.
I work on a Windows server system, which is default FRENCH system, so, problems may also be related to this since system locales are probably related too....

Here is my current system :

```
Windows server 2k12 (up to date)
PostgreSQL 9.4
PgAdmin3 (1.2)
```

Here is the error I get :

```
An error has occurred:

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe7 0x75 0x20
```

The default config I had was this (for the settings that look interesting and related to my problem according to few threads I found about similar issues) :

```
client_encoding : 'sql_ascii'
lc_messages : 'French_France.1252'
lc_* (other lc values are set to French_France.1252 too...)
```

Actually, I tried several values like this :

```
client_encoding : 'UTF8'
lc_messages : 'C','fr_FR.UTF8','French_France.UTF8','Default'
lc_* (other lc values like setting for message)
```

And nothing worked... The error message is still there each time I try to reach the "Server Status" tab in pgAdmin.

The error log seems to be down to since it registers every "n" seconds, the current encoding error.

An interesting thing I noticed is that, when I edit the configuration settings from the pgAdmin interface (and everywhere else, result is the same btw), the "Value" column, does not always correspond to the "Current Value" column.

For example : 
I edited the "client_encoding" value from 'sql_ascii' to 'UTF8' and restarted pg,
Now I get this : 
    value : 'UTF8'
    current value : 'UNICODE'

Whatever I do, looks like there is a problem somewhere.
Only for lc_messages = 'C' then he takes it into account and displays it as 'current value'...

Where's the trick?

Thanks for reading / Help :)

Comment: Don't confuse  _locale support_ and _character set support_. I'd switch all `lc_*` back to  `French_France.1252` and `client_encoding` either to `WIN1252` or keep `UTF8`.

Comment: When I change client_encoding to UTF8, "current value" field keeps its value as "UNICODE" :'(

Comment: It's right, compare http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/multibyte.html

Comment: okay, but even when client_encoding set to utf8 (displayed by postgresql as unicode) I still have the same error...

Comment: These bytes "0xe7 0x75 0x20" mean "çu " in win1252 encoding, as in the french word "reçu". They're not allowed in UTF8 as the error indicates. When you write _Here is the error I get:..._ you might mention when doing what. Just launching pgadmin?